# Change automatically the range of the datasource of a pivot table of each worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I want to change automatically the range of the sourcedata of each pivot table of each worksheet. I have the sheet 'DATA' which feeds every pivot table of the workbook. The point is that the range of the DATA sheet is variable. So when I change the DATA sheet I want to refresh all the pivot table adjusting also the rnew range of data.

I wrote the following script, but it is not working. I don't know why:

```vb
Sub Prueba_Rango_TD()

  Dim ws As Worksheet

  Dim LastRow As Integer   
  LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

  For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets   
 
    For Each tbl In ws.ListObjects

      tbl.Resize tbl.Range.Resize("DATA!B8:O" & Ultima_fila) 
   
    Next tbl   

  Next ws   

End Sub
```

Can you help me please?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe try to have the data source for the pivot table as a dynamic named range. So, when either the data source shrink or expand, you can just directly refresh one of the pivot table which use that data source then other pivot tables using that same data source will be refreshed too. Please read this link : https://www.exceldemy.com/excel-offset-dynamic-range-multiple-columns/

Answer (score 0):

The easy way you do this is by recording a Macro.
Then you will se what type of Objects being used and where the pointer of your first Pivot, something like this:

> ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").ChangePivotCache
> ActiveWorkbook. _
> PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA").UsedRange.Address,
> Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12)

If all the other sheets points towards the same data Cashe you do it with the loop.

> .PivotTables("PivotTable1").ChangePivotCache ("DATA!PivotTable1")
> .PivotTables("PivotTable1").RefreshTable